# Define 'Default Template' for each section

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, templates

Is it possible to define a different 'Default Template' for each parent section on a website? On each page I have 3 images in the sidebar. I want these 3 images to change depending on what section the user is viewing.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With the power of learning!

You can make a template to fit in all of the options that you want on each page.

[Something like](https://github.com/maniator/SmallFry) [an MVC](http://oreilly.com/php/archive/mvc-intro.html) might fit your needs as it seperates the templates from the backend code.

Comment: It's something I'd love to learn but the timescale for this just wouldn't allow it. Need to find an alternative solution, if one exists.

Comment: @Kelvin well see my 1st link, its my own smaller version on an (m)VC

Comment: Thanks for your help @Neal. It's all too confusing for me. Thought it might be easier :(

Comment: @Kelvin just ask any questions you might have ^_^

Comment: Honestly @Neal, wouldn't have a clue where to start. Is there any code I can share to make things easier here?

Comment: @Kelvin googled: https://www.google.com/search?ix=sea&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+templating or i can help with something else.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6397/discussion-between-neal-and-kelvin)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a completely custom Template Hierarchy by filtering 'template_redirect'.

http://phpxref.com/xref/wordpress/wp-includes/template-loader.php.source.html